# haskell style pattern matching of parameter values for function calls in R

Tags: r, haskell, pattern-matching

In R, is it possible to do function pattern matching based on parameter values ala Haskell?

i.e. if parameter x is ='foo', run one version of a function, if x is 'bar', run another version? Obviously this could be done with if statements if necessary, but I'd like to know if there's a more 'functional' approach to it.

For example, to do this kind of function selection (foo1 vs. foo2) automatically without the ifelse statement to do the conditioning:

```
foo1 <- function(a) {
    paste0(a, 'foo1')
}

foo2 <- function(a) {
    paste0('baz', a, 'foo2')
}

x <- 'barp'
value <- ifelse(x == 'barp', foo1(x), foo2(x))
```

Comment: Why not something like [this](http://lpaste.net/119527) ?

Comment: the point is in haskell it could be one function that handles both cases, dispatching one or the other depending on the parameter value. Also I'm looking for the R equivalent of Haskell, not Haskell code.

Comment: I found [this](http://mentalmodels.princeton.edu/skhemlani/2013/02/16/ml-like-pattern-matching-and-its-limitations-in-r/) which seems to extend R to add a limited form of pattern matching.

Comment: There is a package called lambda.r which I think addresses pattern matching and guards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general algebraic data types, you can define your own matching function helpers. These are sometimes called "eliminators", and essentially convert your ADT values into their Church encoding.

For instance, let's translate this Haskell code snipppet:

```hs
x = Just 3
y = Nothing
a = case x of Nothing -> 42 ; Just w -> w+100
b = case y of Nothing -> 42 ; Just w -> w+100
```

The result is:

```r
# eliminator
matchMaybe <- function(x,kn,kj) {
   ifelse(x[[1]]=='Nothing', kn(), kj(x[[2]]))
}

# tests
x <- list('Just', 3)
y <- list('Nothing')
a <- matchMaybe(x
               ,function() { 42 }
               ,function(w){ w+100 })
b <- matchMaybe(y
               ,function() { 42 }
               ,function(w){ w+100 })
```

Note, however, that *deep* pattern matching is hard to translate in this way.
That is, in Haskell you can do stuff like

```hs
case x of Just 10 -> 22 ; Nothing -> 42 ; Just w -> w+100
```

wherein you match the `Just` constructor and the inner `10` at the same time. This can not be encoded in a convenient way.

For strings, as in the OP example, a possible eliminator could be:

```r
match <- function(x,v,kt,ke) {
   ifelse(x==v, kt(),ke(x))
}

r <- match('foo'
     , 'bar', function() { "then" }
     ,        function(x) { "else" })
```

Also keep in mind that I am not fluent in R, so there might be a much better approach.

Comment: I must admit I'm not familiar with church encoding. This seems somewhat involved/complicated, but I guess trying to achieve pattern matching is "fighting" the language somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done based on the "class" of the object, but not the value.  I am not super familiar with Haskell, but I though Haskell also dispatches on class/type rather than actual value?  Here is the R implementation:

```
> foo <- function(a) UseMethod("foo")
> foo.1 <- function(a) paste(a, 'foo1')
> foo.2 <- function(a) paste('baz', a, 'foo2')
> 
> obj_1 <- structure("hello world", class="1")
> obj_2 <- structure("hello world", class="2")
> 
> foo(obj_1)
[1] "hello world foo1"
> foo(obj_2)
[1] "baz hello world foo2"
```

This will only dispatch based on the class of the first argument.  You can use S4 methods if you want to dispatch based on multiple arguments.

Comment: haskell can pattern match on value. it's somewhat of a language idiom, for example http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions